# What is the appropriate HTTP status code for a password protected page?

Tags: authentication, http-headers, httpresponse

What is the appropriate HTTP status code for a password protected page?

If `/some-page.html` is protected, the login form is presented on that URL; it doesn't redirect to a dedicated login page.

I was thinking 401 would be suitable, but the RFC states:

> The response MUST include a
>   WWW-Authenticate header field (section
>   14.46) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP 401 response code makes sense if you're relying on the HTTP protocol to handle your authentication. In you case, you're not. You're relying on data submitted in your HTML page.

In your case, HTTP has done it's job: it's delivered data (the HTML page and form) to the client successfully and a 200 response code is appropriate in this case.

Comment: With that argument, wouldn't customized 404 pages with HTTP/404 be unnecessary? As I see it, the 401 would tell the Google bots among others, that this URL shouldn't be indexed yet.

Comment: I don't think so. The 404 status code is telling the client that the requested object wasn't found. The status code is correctly informing the client that their request wasn't found irrespective of the custom content in the response. If you're trying to control the behaviour of search engine crawlers, perhaps use a `noindex` meta tag (http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710&from=61050&rd=1) or add an entry to your `robots.txt`.

Comment: Yes, that would be a way to work around the problem. But if 404 tells the client the requested object wasn't found, wouldn't 401 tell the client the requested object needs authorization?

Comment: Sure, if you're relying on the HTTP protocol to handle the authentication. Can you use digest authentication in your app? (or basic authentication over SSL)